# Batch Script : zip the file and save. Copy the log to a file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, logging, windows-scripting

I have SourceDirectory(source directory) ,BackupDestination(destination directory for backup) and DestinationLog(destination directory for logs). 
When the batch script is executed the purpose is to zip the file in source directory and save it to backup directory.The output which is the **log** has to be saved to .txt file in DestinationLog folder.
The name of the log file should be the "BuildScript_V1_" followed by current date and time.
When I am executing the batch file, the execution process is running infinite times.
I am new to programming.I couldn't figure it out even though similar cases are solved in many sources.

```
@echo off

SET SourceDirectory = C:\Users\Folder\Downloads\Batch_Files\Source\

SET BackupDestination = C:\Users\Folder\Downloads\Batch_Files\Backup

SET DestinationLog = C:\Users\Folder\Downloads\Batch_Files\Logs


set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%

set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%

set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%

set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%

if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%

set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%

set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%-%CUR_MM%-%CUR_DD%_%CUR_HH%-%CUR_NN%-%CUR_SS%

CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDirectory%"') DO (

    7z.exe a "%BackupDestination%\%%~NF.zip" "%SourceDirectory%\%%~NXF"
)

xcopy /s "C:\Users\Folder\Downloads\Batch_Files\Source\" "C:\Users\Folder\Downloads\Batch_Files\Backup"

C:\Users\Folder\Desktop\Backup_Log.bat>C:\Users\Folder\Downloads\Batch_Files\Logs\BuildScript_V1_%SUBFILENAME%.log
```

Comment: Either change all instances of `%SourceDirectory%`, `%BackupDestination%` and `%DestinationLog%`, to `%SourceDirectory %`, `%BackupDestination %` and `%DestinationLog %` respectively, or modify these like this `SET SourceDirectory = `, `SET BackupDestination = ` and `SET DestinationLog = ` to `SET SourceDirectory=`, `SET BackupDestination=` and `SET DestinationLog=`. _(Your spaces on each side of the `=` character are being included in both the variable name and value)_.

Comment: I have done as such. Now it is possible to create the zip files in backup folder.But the log files are continuously creating and it is not stopping. I only want to create a  **single .txt log file for single execution of batch file.**

Comment: If you're individually zipping every file in a directory, it may be prudent to exclude `.zip` files at either the `DIR` stage, _(perhaps using `findstr`)_, or in the `DO` portion, _(using an `if` command with `%%~xF`)_. You don't really want to potentially zip `.zip` files, do you?

Comment: You've also created variables, yet seem not to have used them in all cases. Your bottom two lines can both use the variables defined at the beginning.